# Laravel 8 Uploading Contents Of A Folder In S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to find a way to upload a folder, and its subfolders and files.

Uploading the folder by zipping it and then unzipping it locally works, but when the zip/unzip process is within S3, it fails.

I would like to do either of the following:

- Upload zip files in Amazon S3 and unzip the said file back into S3
- Upload a folder's content directly into S3 (the folder's subfolders and files)